# Referencing Schemas in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pass-by-reference

I have a couple models that are in going to be held in separate files and I can't seem to find a way to reference them without resorting to having them in the same file.

My first file contains the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  hash_password: {
    type: String
  },
  /* etc */
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.hash_password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And the second file is this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ThreadSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  created_by: {
    type: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    required: true
  }
  /* etc */
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Threads', ThreadSchema);
```

I keep getting this error: "TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `created_by.required`". The code works if I keep the user and thread models in the same file but when I separate the files, they no longer can reference each other. I tried adding require('./userModel') at the top of the threadModel but that didn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried importing this:
var User = require('./userModel');

Comment: Interestingly, when I removed the required on created_by, everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: have you tried with this: `created_by: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' , required: true }`